# 'QScrollBar:vertical' not valid when put together with other sub-control in QComboBox stylesheet

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am using Qt Creator 4.5.2 (Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3.0 64-bit) and running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a QComboBox and am trying to set it stylesheet. But, I am having the following problems:

If I do:

```
setStyleSheet("selection-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);");
```

Or

```
setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical {background: red;}");
```

separately, the stylesheet is valid.

But, if I put them together, like:

```
setStyleSheet("selection-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); QScrollBar:vertical {background: red;}");
```

The stylesheet is Invalid. I already tried both in code and in QT Designer. In coding, I got this: Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x555556118eb0.
In QT designer, it simply states 'Invalid Style Sheet'

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you indicate it can be deduced that if you set the properties without indicating the widget classes as a selector then it will be assumed that the properties will affect the same widget but it seems that if you set at least one selector then you must set the selectors to all the elements, in your case you could use:

```
QComboBox{selection-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
QScrollBar:vertical{background: red;}
```

Comment: A question: What is the difference between "QComboBox{selection-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}" and "selection-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"  when set  the object's Stylesheet of a QComboBox. It looked like the same to me but it acted quite different when I tested them separately.